# resources to study smalltalk and pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have downloaded the pharobyexample.org ebook, but it seems out of sync with the latest release of pharo, also I would like to know about resources  which can help me learn smalltalk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a bit outdated (or a lot :P), PharoByExample is still the best way to learn you can find around. You can download the image provided in the web page: http://www.pharobyexample.org/image/PBE-OneClick-1.1.app.zip (is not very visible, I'm sorry), and use it to learn... then you can jump to the latest version and you will find all you learned will apply with almost no change :)

You can find other sources to learn, but they are much more distant to the "up to date" versions you can find around: http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks.html

You also can look around: http://pharo.org/documentation, there are some good stuff there (including links to Pharo by example, of course!).

Finally, you can also suscribe to pharo-users@lists.pharo.org list... is a list where you can make any questions you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is an updated PBE that you can find here

https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/view/Books/job/UpdatedPharoByExample/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/book-result/UpdatedPharoByExample.pdf

other books you can use is this

http://deepintopharo.com/

and this

https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/PharoForTheEnterprise/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EnterprisePharo.pdf

there are also books you can build by yourself, those are created by executing the download.sh and then the compile.sh scripts. The first script will download Pillar which is a Pharo library that can generate html files.

Building the docs yourself is a very good idea if you want to get the very latest docs for Pharo.

Those books can be found here

https://github.com/SquareBracketAssociates

if you want to also generate a pdf then you will need to install Latex depending on your OS.

All together there is a ton of documentation out there. Unfortunately because most books are very recent , there has not be care to make it easily accessible and visible to newcomers.

Answer (score 3):

pharo-users@lists.pharo.org is also the place to ask for questions if you get stuck in pharo-by-example. If you find any problems with the book, we would certainly like to know about them.

You can also ask questions on IRC (as i have seen you doing) but you need to hang out longer to get any answers. Most pharo users and developers are in different timezones, so they are not usually awake at the same times as you.

update: a while ago the pharo community moved from IRC on to discord. you can find the link on the pharo community page: http://pharo.org/community

Comment: Glad to know about the mailing list. I am new to IRC, will keep the things in mind next time.